# How to open .jp2 with GRASS 7.0.3

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, grass-7.0

Does anyone know if I can use Grass to open a .jp2 image file? I am aiming to do some image classification on the image and when I try to import the image into the program a stream of errors comes up in the side window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRASS GIS is using GDAL as backend for reading and writing raster and vector data. If your GDAL installation supports JP2 then also GRASS GIS will import these data.

Please post more information about the GRASS GIS and GDAL version you use.

Comment: At the moment we are using 7.0.4 for grass. Where would I find out what GDAL version we are using?

Comment: Right, ive got it to load but for some reason it is having an issue with the NIR layer of the jp2 image. Can Grass deal with layer 4?

Comment: This is the error for the NIR layer

ERROR: Error writing null row 60158 of <img_2012_08_50cm_bgrn.4>

Comment: GRASS GIS can deal with an "unlimited" number of layers/channels. Perhaps your disk is simply full?

Comment: Concering the GDAL version: "gdal-config --version" will tell you